# ASP.NET Core 2 Authorize attribute jwt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

Please tell me why this code doesn't work.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey()
            };
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

I tried delete `options.Default*` and replace it to only `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`. Just only if I change `[Authorize]` to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` it works. But I don't want use `AuthenticationSchemes` property for each attribute.

Comment: Do you have other authentication or identity related stuff in your Startup?

Comment: @poke I updated my code. please check

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`services.AddIdentity(…)` sets up ASP.NET Core Identity which registers multiple Cookie authentication schemes using the Cookie authentication which are required for the form-based identity logins to work.

As part of that, it also sets up the default authentication and challenge schemes to `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`.

Since you call `AddIdentity` *after* `AddAuthentication`, the default configuration you did for the latter will be overwritten by the identity configuration. So to fix your problem, you will have to make sure that you set the default schemes in the identity options *after* registering Identity.

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();;

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(…);
```

Note that this will *obviously* stop the authentication cookie of ASP.NET Core Identity to be the default authentication and challenge scheme. So if your application *also* has areas where your are not using JWT Bearer, then those will stop working and will require explicit `Authenticate` attributes to switch back to the Identity cookie.